# ¿Cómo hacer para desenfocar imagen de fondo en Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Quería saber cómo puedo lograr un efecto desenfocado en [android-studio](/questions/tagged/android-studio). No lo hago con Photoshop o software similar porque es el perfil del usuario y la foto que tiene de perfil es esa la foto que se desenfoca de fondo.

Por ese motivo debe ser **dinámico**.

Esta es la imagen de ejemplo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: desenfocado te refieres a blur  de la imagen pero en el fondo?

Comment: Si, me refiero a eso. A que tenga ese efecto en el fondo

Comment: Me explicarías como sería mediante el sdk?

Comment: dale elena, muchas gracias

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Primero la colocas de fondo igual que la colocas como principal, para hacer el efecto puedes usar la libreria Blurry, simplemente hay que agregarla a tu proyecto por medio de Graddle.

[Blurry:](https://github.com/wasabeef/Blurry)

Solo agrega esto en tu archivo Graddle app y podrás utilizar la librería.

```
    dependencies {
       compile 'jp.wasabeef:blurry:2.0.2'
    }
```

Agrega esta actividad de ejemplo a tu aplicación, en ella puedes ver el funcionamiento de la librería.

**activity_example.xml**

Agrega un drawable a las vistas, para que puedas ver el efecto.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.ExampleActivity">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/spacer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/right_top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/spacer"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/spacer"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/serv"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/spacer"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/spacer"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/serv"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/right_bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/spacer"
        android:layout_below="@id/spacer"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/serv"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/left_bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/spacer"
        android:layout_below="@id/spacer"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/serv"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/overlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@null"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="88sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**ExampleActivity.java**

```
public class ExampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_example);

        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override public void onClick(View v) {

                long startMs = System.currentTimeMillis();
                Blurry.with(getApplicationContext())
                        .radius(25)
                        .sampling(1)
                        .color(Color.argb(66, 0, 255, 255))
                        .async()
                        .capture(findViewById(R.id.right_top))
                        .into((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.right_top));

                Blurry.with(getApplicationContext())
                        .radius(10)
                        .sampling(8)
                        .async()
                        .capture(findViewById(R.id.right_bottom))
                        .into((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.right_bottom));

                Blurry.with(getApplicationContext())
                        .radius(25)
                        .sampling(1)
                        .color(Color.argb(66, 255, 255, 0))
                        .async()
                        .capture(findViewById(R.id.left_bottom))
                        .into((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.left_bottom));

                Log.d(getString(R.string.app_name),
                        "TIME " + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() - startMs) + "ms");
            }
        });

        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

            private boolean blurred = false;

            @Override public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                if (blurred) {
                    Blurry.delete((ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.content));
                } else {
                    long startMs = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    Blurry.with(getApplicationContext())
                            .radius(25)
                            .sampling(2)
                            .async()
                            .animate(500)
                            .onto((ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.content));
                    Log.d(getString(R.string.app_name),
                            "TIME " + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() - startMs) + "ms");
                }

                blurred = !blurred;
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Iniciar en onCreate:**

Dado que es un cambio visual en tiempo de ejecución, es necesario manejar la transformación dentro de un thread.

Primero tu imagen debe estar contenida dentro de una View(Layout) y a este se aplicara el cambio.

**activity_example.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.ExampleActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/serv"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**ExampleActivity.java:**

```
public class ExampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private View rootView;

    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_blurry);

        rootView = (View) findViewById(R.id.content);

        rootView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Blurry.with(getApplicationContext()).radius(25).sampling(2).onto((ViewGroup) rootView);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y con esa librería después como aplicó el efecto a la imagen ? Gracias

Comment: Listo, ya esta agregado.

Comment: He implementado todo tal cual dijiste pero a las imagenes no se le aplica el efecto

Comment: el problema es el siguiente. me larga nulPointerException en todo el codigo de la activity.java

Comment: Copia el ejemplo tal cual y coloca la actividad en la primer activity declarada del manifest, para que puedas ver como funciona.

Comment: Estas declarando una variable que no tiene objeto como tal, la clase esta completa, verifica que tus variables esten inicializadas.

Comment: ya he podido dejar 1 sola image con el efecto aprentando el boton, lo que quiero lograr es poder hacer que el efecto se haga solo en el imageView que tengo sin tener que presionar el boton

Comment: Lo agrego a la respuesta

Comment: excelente muchas gracias, funciona perfecto, ahora te hago una ultima pregunta. Es posible ponerle un background al LinearLayout y que cambie ese fondo en vez de tener un ImageView?

Comment: Si, mientras ese linear sea el mismo que inicializas en la actividad como rootView. Saludos

Comment: tengo una duda, la imagen se desenfoca bien, el problema es que si ejecuto la app, no se pone borrosa, pero si mientras se esta ejecutando la app le cambio el valor al radius y la ejecuto de nuevo ( sin parar la app para volver a ejecutar) ahi si se pone borrosa, tengo el metodo dentro del onCreate

Comment: Esta pregunta ya esta contestada, genera una nueva pregunta especificando las herramientas que usas y agrega tu codigo. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Pongo esto en una respuesta porque es un poco grande.

Añadiendo algo mas a la respuesta de @Max Sandoval creo que aparte de la librería debes añadir [RenderScript](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/compute.html) a tu build.gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19

        renderscriptTargetApi 18
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true

    }
}
```

Es lo que yo tuve que hacer para que funcionara.
Un saludo.

Comment: Como componente extra ayuda al rendimiento, así que seria muy buena idea agregarlo. Saludos.