# ¿ Cómo poner un relative con un fondo difuminado como en la imagen adjunta?

Tags: java, android

¿ Hay algún `Theme` en `Eclipse` que haga esto o alguien ha usado este tipo de fondo ?  Es exactamente lo que busco pero con cualquier color que uso lógicamente se me queda mate, no es el resultado, debe ser translúcido.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

UPDATE:

Mi código xml donde tengo un botón que es el que tengo que modificar para que se aplique a todos, ya que tengo una lista como en el ejemplo:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
>

 <RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
     android:background="@drawable/translucido" >

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/cargo"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:text="Medium Text"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/nombre"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/cargo"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_marginBottom="21dp"
         android:gravity="left"
         android:text="     Large Text"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
         android:textStyle="bold"
         android:typeface="serif" />

 </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Claro, es una captura de un ejemplo que habia por Internet de modos de personalizar una App y me ha gustado, y claro, son translucidos los elementos, me he dado ya cuenta, el fondo es una imagen y lo que hace es como distorsionar el fondo de los elementos para dar esa sensacion .

Comment: Tengo lo mismo que ahí, una lista con unos items y una pantalla donde tengo 1 solo botón que es lo que después se duplica. La idea es dar translucidez a ese botón y ya se aplica a todos, te paso el código de mi xml claro.

Comment: Mira a ver si [esto te sirve](http://desarrollador-android.com/material-design/desarrollo-material-design/layouts-desarrollo/personalizar-navigation-bar/)

Comment: He cambiado la pregunta porque lo que me has pasado em ha hecho darme cuenta que no es translucido, si no **difuminado** ya que translucido sí que se ve la imagen de fondo y mi ejemplo esta como difuminado sin distinguir

Comment: bueno, según la física, lo translúcido no es un estado binario. puede ser muy poco translúcido y por ello casi transparente, o tan translúcido que sea casi opaco xD pero si hay una propiedad `difuminado` pues perfect xD

Comment: entonces como hizo eso xd

Comment: @RfMvs ¿La pregunta es para que te recomienden una solución o cómo programarlo? Por favor no caigamos en algo basado en opiniones

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cómo hacer para desenfocar imagen de fondo en Android?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/13861/c%c3%b3mo-hacer-para-desenfocar-imagen-de-fondo-en-android)

Comment: sólo debes de agregar aplha en XML y en java `setAlpha`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

El efecto se conoce como *blur*. No es muy recomendado utilizarlo por el gran consumo de memoria que tiene. Pero hay librerías que te ayudan a generar dicho efecto. Si te interesa puedes puedes ver esta librería: https://github.com/faradaj/BlurBehind

Comment: Hola Romelapj, esto no es una buena respuesta ya que solo es un enlace. deberias poner algun ejemplo de codigo. Tal y como está parece un comentario (y si, se que no tienes reputacion para comentar, pero cada cosa en su sitio ^^) un saludo y animo hasta los 50 rep

Comment: Gracias, no lo he implementado al finalpero era el blur lo que buscaba.