# Como hacer un imageview mas grande al darle clic

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

Tengo una galería en mi app, con un `GridLayout` y quiero que cuando el usuario le de clic a alguna imagen tenga **[este](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dewYt.jpg)** efecto , ¿Cómo puedo lograr eso? 
Si me pudieran decir que efecto seria ese o alguna librería que lo hace seria de gran ayuda muchas gracias

**ADAPTER**

```
public class GalleryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GalleryAdapter.ViewHolder> 
{
    private ArrayList<Business> businessList;
    private FragmentActivity activity;
    private int layoutMolde,position;

    public ViewImageExtended viewImageExtended;
    public Bitmap bitmap = null;

    public GalleryAdapter(FragmentActivity activity, ArrayList<Business> list, int layout)
    {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.businessList = list;
        layoutMolde = layout;
    }

    @Override
    public GalleryAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_gallery_premium, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position)
    {

        if(businessList.size()==0){
            holder.Imggallerypremium.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else {
            Log.d("ARRAY", businessList.toString());
         Glide.with(activity).load(businessList.get(position).getImage())
                    .into(holder.Imggallerypremium);
        }



    }

    @Override

    public int getItemCount() {

        return (businessList == null) ? 0 : businessList.size();


    }



    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {

        public ImageView Imggallerypremium;

        public ViewHolder( View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);
            Imggallerypremium = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgGalleryPremium);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)(Imggallerypremium.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                    if(viewImageExtended == null || viewImageExtended.getDialog() == null || !viewImageExtended.getDialog().isShowing()){

                        FragmentManager fm = this.activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
                        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();

                        // Aqui le pasas el bitmap de la imagen
                        arguments.putParcelable("PROFILE_PICTURE", bitmap);
                        viewImageExtended = ViewImageExtended.newInstance(arguments);
                        viewImageExtended.show(fm, "ViewImageExtended");

                    }

                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**ACTIVITY**

```
public class BusinessPremiumGallery extends AppCompatActivity
{
GalleryAdapter galleryAdapter;
    Gson gson;
    public ViewImageExtended viewImageExtended;
    public Bitmap bitmap = null;
    private static final Type BUSINESS_TYPE = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Business>>() {}.getType();

    JsonObject images;
    GridLayoutManager layoutManager;
    ArrayList<Business> arrayGallery;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_business_premium_gallery);
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        final int values = bundle.getInt("no");
        new PlifRequestBase(BusinessPremiumGallery.this) {

            @Override
            public JsonObject onHttpOk(JsonObject response) throws JSONException {
                JsonObject respuesta, details, location, geolocation, matrix, schedules_array;
                JsonArray data,branches, phones, schedules,extra_services,user_images;
                respuesta = response;
                int catalog_id;
                String catalog_descrip,catalog_name,catalog_image,image;

                Log.d("VALUES2",String.valueOf(values));
                arrayGallery=new ArrayList<Business>();
                gson=new Gson();
                user_images= respuesta.get("user_images").getAsJsonArray();


                if(user_images.size()<0){
                    arrayGallery=null;
                    images=null;

                }else {
                    arrayGallery=gson.fromJson(user_images,BUSINESS_TYPE);
                    for (int i = 0; i < user_images.size(); i++) {
                        images = user_images.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
                        image=images.get("image").getAsString();
                       Log.d("IMAGES",image);
                        Log.d("CATALOG",String.valueOf(images));

                    }


                }
                if (BusinessPremiumGallery.this == null)
                    return response;
                BusinessPremiumGallery.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        RecyclerView recycler = (RecyclerView) BusinessPremiumGallery.this.findViewById(R.id.recycler_gallery);
                        galleryAdapter = new GalleryAdapter(BusinessPremiumGallery.this, arrayGallery, R.layout.row_gallery_premium);
                        recycler.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
                        layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(BusinessPremiumGallery.this, 2);
                        recycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                        recycler.setAdapter(galleryAdapter);
                    }

                });

                return respuesta;
            }

            @Override
            public void onHttpCreate(JsonObject response) throws JSONException
            {

            }
        }.execute("businesses/"+String.valueOf(values), "GET");
    }





}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes crear un DialogFragment y cargar la imagen ahi:

```
public class ViewImageExtended extends AppCompatDialogFragment {

    public Bitmap PICTURE_SELECTED;
    public static ViewImageExtended newInstance(Bundle arguments) {
        Bundle args = arguments;
        ViewImageExtended fragment = new ViewImageExtended();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public ViewImageExtended() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Esta linea de código hace que tu DialogFragment sea Full screen
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, android.R.style.Theme_NoTitleBar);
        Bundle arguments = getArguments();
        PICTURE_SELECTED = arguments.getParcelable("PICTURE_SELECTED");
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_fragment_view_image, container, false);

        ImageView ivImage = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);

        if(PICTURE_SELECTED != null)
           ivImage.setImageBitmap(PICTURE_SELECTED);

        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity(), getTheme()){
            @Override
            public void onBackPressed() {
                // Aqui puedes capturar el OnBackPressed
                dismiss();
            }
        };
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        return dialog;
    }

}
```

**dialog_fragment_view_image.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

      <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Declara una variable global en tu actividad:

```
public ViewImageExtended viewImageExtended;
public Bitmap bitmap = null; // El bitmap de la imagen
public FragmentActivity activity; // En el constructor del fragment pasas el activity como referencia this.activity = activity;
```

Para inicializar el Dialog desde una actividad en tu OnClick (recuerda que a este paso, debes tener almacenado el bitmap de la imagen cuando des click en la variable `bitmap`):

```
// Esto es para evitar crear cuadros de diálogos varias veces 
if(viewImageExtended == null || viewImageExtended.getDialog() == null || !viewImageExtended.getDialog().isShowing()){

  // Si estas en un activity
  FragmentManager fm = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
  // Si estas en un fragment y pasaste el activity en el constructor
  FragmentManager fm = this.activity.getSupportFragmentManager();

  Bundle arguments = new Bundle();

  // Aqui le pasas el bitmap de la imagen
  arguments.putParcelable("PROFILE_PICTURE", bitmap);
  viewImageExtended = ViewImageExtended.newInstance(arguments);
  viewImageExtended.show(fm, "ViewImageExtended");
  }
```

}

Recuerda, puedes customizar el layout **dialog_fragment_view_image.xml** como quieras, agregar botones, etc...

**Ese tipo de efecto Blur, suele venir en aplicaciones iOS, puedes buscar** [referencias de como hacer un efecto blur a una imagen](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/13861/c%C3%B3mo-hacer-para-desenfocar-imagen-de-fondo-en-android) **y cargarla de fondo.**

Espero te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta y parece que si podria resolver mi problema, estaba tratando de implementarlo pero se me complica por que en mi app tengo un recycler y un adapter entonces no se que codigo va en que parte jaja no se si me pudieras orientar por favor :)

Comment: Claro, implementa el código que incluí en mi respuesta. En el adaptador implementa OnClickListener para los items (imágenes) de tu RecyclerView y en el OnClick agrega el código para mostrar el DialogFragment que te adjunté más arriba. Y en el mismo método OnClick, obténel bitmap de tu referencia al objeto del imageview quedaría asi:   bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) referenciaDeLaImagen.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

Comment: Muchas gracias deja lo intento :)

Comment: Dejame saber como te va, saludos.

Comment: No pude :/ agregué mi codigo en mi pregunta, me marca error en getsupportFragment :/ no se si este haciendo algo mal, espero puedas ayudarme, muchas gracias

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57445/discussion-between-andrespengineer-and-heber-solis).

Answer (score 0):

O podrias utilizar esta dependencia 
https://github.com/mzelzoghbi/ZGallery?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=4987

Para crear galerias con Zoom y todo ;)

Comment: ya lo implemente y si corre mi app pero cuando le doy clic a una imagen no hace nada :/ y en la pagina no viene muy explicado como lograr eso :(

Comment: Tienes razón , ya logre hacer que funcionara pero pero no es muy moldeable, utiliza la solución de arriba, es lo mas facil y practico. @HeberSolis

Comment: Muy bien, De todos modos muchas gracias por tu ayuda :D