# Abrir ImageView en Fragment al hacer clic en ImageView

Tags: java, android

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que cada vez que haga clic en una imagen está se abra en un `Fragment`?

He hecho lo siguiente, no sé si será el método adecuado pero es lo que se me ha ocurrido.

Mi clase principal: Aquí tengo las tres `ImageView` donde hago clic y abro el `Fragment`:

```
    image1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

            DialogFragment newFragment = MyDialogFragment.newInstance();
            newFragment.show(ft, "tag");
        }
    });

    image2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

            DialogFragment newFragment = MyDialogFragment.newInstance();
            newFragment.show(ft, "tag");
        }
    });

    image3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

            DialogFragment newFragment = MyDialogFragment.newInstance();
            newFragment.show(ft, "tag");
        }
    });
```

`Fragment`:

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {


    static MyDialogFragment newInstance() {

        return new MyDialogFragment();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_my_dialog_fragment, container, false);


        return view;
    }
}
```

`activity_my_dialog_fragment`:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imagefragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer que cada vez que haga clic en una de las imágenes de mi `clase` principal se abra el `Fragment` pero que se muestra ahí la imagen en la que he hecho clic?

Comment: Lo pongo en comentario ya que no estoy seguro de si es lo que buscas. Has probado a pasar un argumento usando `Bundle` ? Tal y como se haría en un intent. ` Bundle argumentos = new Bundle(); argumentos.putInt("imagen", R....); newFragment.setArguments(argumentos);`
Y en `onCreate()` de tu clase `MyDialogFragment` obtenerlo. Pasas como dato, por ejemplo, la uri de la imagen y la colocas en el `imageView`

Comment: Podrías poner una respuesta con más detalles? Si lo que realiza lo que me comentas es abrir el `DialogFragment` con la `imageView` que selecciono aquí `Bundle argumentos = new Bundle(); argumentos.putInt("imagen", R.drawable.ic_launcher_round); newFragment.setArguments(argumentos);` sí! Es lo que busco :), pero no sé como realizar lo que me comentas en el `onCreate()` de mi `MyDialogFragment` podrías explicarmelo en una respuesta? @Israel

Comment: Puede sonar ordinario y si usas ImageButton

Comment: ¿Por qué usando ImageButton funcionaría?¿Cómo se haría? Intenta añadir más datos a tu respuesta, tal y como está ahora no es de mucha utilidad.

Comment: Duplicado de:  https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/64052/38154 es eso lo que quieres hacer?

Comment: Ya ví esa respuesta pero no conseguí hacer lo que quería, por lo tanto abrí esta pregunta, gracias @Andrespengineer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agrega un `Bundle` al iniciar el `DialogFragment` agregando como extra el `Drawable`:

```
Bundle argumentos = new Bundle(); 
argumentos.putInt("imagen", R.drawable.ic_launcher_round); 
DialogFragment newFragment = MyDialogFragment.newInstance();
newFragment.setArguments(argumentos);
newFragment.show(ft, "tag");
```

Para obtener el `id` del `Drawable` lo obtienes de la siguiente manera:

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    static MyDialogFragment newInstance() {

        return new MyDialogFragment();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_my_dialog_fragment, container, false);

        //tu imageview
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imagefragment);


        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        if (bundle != null) {
          int myInt = bundle.getInt("imagen", 0);
          imageView.setImageResource(myInt);
        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

La referencia del `Drawable` es unicamente un `int`, pero con este sistema puedes pasar cualquier elemento.

Comment: Gracias @Israel ! Justo lo que necesitaba :)

Answer (score -1):

Puede sonar ordinario y si usas ImageButton, estoy haciendo un reproductor de musica y en vez de usar imagenes directamente uso ImageButton con las imagenes de previus play y next

**Editado**

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm;
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft;  

ImageButton btn=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.Button)


 btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MyDialogFragment dl=newMyDialogFragment();
                fm=getSupportFragmentManager();
                ft=fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.Container,dl);
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.commit();
            }
        });
```

Donde container es el contenedor que deseas reemplazar ya sea un RelativeLayout etc

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta! Pero la de @Israel era justo lo que buscaba.